# Cannot understand JavaScript instruction

Tags: javascript

I am interested in the [Wasabi](https://github.com/atstp/wasabi) tool.
Please have a look on [this piece of code](https://github.com/atstp/wasabi#in-a-browser).

I don't understand this instruction:

```
var W = window.Wasabi = window.Wasabi || {};
```

My final purpose is to adjust a CSS property, dynamically loaded by the JavaScript...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks to all for these good and prompt answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 not-so-obvious things in this statement. There's the 2 consecutive equals, and the `||` at the end. They are not related so Ill tackle them one by one.

```
var W=window.Wasabi=window.Wasabi;
//Shorthand for
var window.Wasabi=window.Wasabi;
var W=window.Wasabi;
```

In english, that'd be: W equals window.Wasabi which equals window.Wasabi.

Now, the `||` is an `OR` in an operation, it states to take the left most value, if it's a truthy value, OR the one on the right.

```
var window.Wasabi=window.Wasabi||{};
//equates to 
var window.Wasabi;
if(window.Wasabi){
    window.Wasabi=window.Wasabi;
}else{
    window.Wasabi={};
}
```

This pattern is very useful to give a default value to a variable. This will answer that Wasabi is at least an object...

Answer (score 3):

Two things going on here.

- Logical OR operator:

`a||b` will return `a` if `a` is truthy or `b` otherwise.

so `window.Wasabi||{}` mean return `window.Wasabi` if it is defined or otherwise return a new empty object.

- Double assignment:

`c=d=1` set `d` equal to `1` and `c` equal to `d`. i.e. set `c` and `d` to `1`.

- Putting these two things together:

if `window.Wasabi` is set already then just get a reference to it and store that in `W`. Otherwise create a new object, store a reference in `window.Wasabi` (to use next time) and call it `W` for use now.

Answer (score 2):

If window.Wasabi doesn't exist, then window.Wasabi will be equal to {}. If it already exist, then don't change it. Finally, assign W to window.Wasabi. So, it would be like this code:

```
var W;

if (!window.Wasabi) {
    window.Wasabi = {};
}
W = window.Wasabi;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main javascript concepts to understand in this statement.

#### The first one is :

```
var x = y || {}
```

This is equivalent to :

```
if (y)
  x = y
else {
  x = {}
```

If `y` is truethy, then its value will be assigned to `x`. Else, `x` will be equal to `{}` (an empty object)

#### The second one is :

```
a = b = "something"
```

`b` will be assigned the value "something" and `a` will be assigned the value of `b` (which was just set to "something")

Both a and b will be assigned the value "something".

#### Application to your example :

```
var W=window.Wasabi=window.Wasabi||{};
```

If window.Wasabi *is not* defined (or is falsy), then it will be assigned to `{}`. 
Then the W variable will be assigned the value of window.Wasabi.

Is `window.Wasabi` *is* defined, then it will be assigned to the value of itself (nothing will happen), and W will be assigned the value of window.Wasabi.

It's a pretty dirty way to set the initial value of an object if it doesn't exist, but... it works.